# Not having the train model in Generic Assistant

Tags: python, nlp, neural-network, speech-recognition

In book `GenericAssistant`, when we enter the data from file `json`, we have to press `train_modle`, but when I press `train_modle`, it says there is no such module!

```
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk

import speech_recognition as spr
import pyttsx3 as tts

from neuralintents import GenericAssistant.train_modle()

class ass:
    def __init__(self):
        
        
        self.rcgr = spr.Recognizer()
        self.speaker = tts.init()
        self.speaker.setProperty("rate" , 150)
         
        self.ass = GenericAssistant("intense.json")
        > ***** self.ass.train_modle() ***** 

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.lable = tk.Label(text="" , font=("Arial" , 120 , "bold"))
        self.lable.pack()

        threading.Thread(target=self.run_ass).start()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def run_ass(self):
        while True:
            try:
                with spr.Microphone() as mic:

                    self.rcgr.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic , duration= 0.2)
                    audio = self.rcgr.listen(mic)

                    text = self.rcgr.recognize_sphinx(audio)
                    text = text.lower()
                    
                    if "hey jake" in text:
                        self.lable.config(fg="red")

                        audio = self.rcgr.listen(mic)
                        text = self.rcgr.recognize_sphinx(audio)
                        text = text.lower()

                        if text == "stop":
                            self.speaker.say("Good Bye")
                            self.speaker.runAndWait()
                            
                            self.speaker.stop()
                            self.root.destroy()
                            sys.exit()

                        else:
                            if text is not None :
                                rsp = self.ass.requste(text)
                                if rsp is not None:
                                    self.speaker.say(rsp)
                                    self.speaker.runAndWait()

                            self.lable.config(fg="black")

            except:
                self.lable.config(fg="black")
                continue


ass()
```

If you think of a method, I would be grateful if you could share it with me.

Comment: It's spelled "model" not "modle". The method is `train_model`.

Comment: says again that there is no such thing...

Comment: You fixed your import statement right? This is not how you import a class: `from neuralintents import GenericAssistant.train_modle()`